# Jenkinfile from SCM choose different branch on application code

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is what I want to do but I don´t know if it possible.

I have ansible  code in bitbucket that jenkins uses to deploy some java applications.
This ansible code has jenkinsfile (among other stuff) that is used for a piepeline and deploy JAVA applications.

this code is called by jenkins like this.

[image]

Developers have 4 jobs that do the deploy for 4 enviroments (dev-qa-stg-prd) but they only have dev and prod branch for the moment

Thing is that the devolopers want now to be able to choose the branch before the job starts, of the java code (dev or prod(master). (example: QA job choose master branch , DEV job choose dev branch and so on)

I know that with jenkins you can choose branch with git parameter plug in, but for this case that would be TO CHOOSE ANSILBE CODE, which is the one that does the job  instead of the JAva application code (which is in the jenkinsfile)

[image]

Is is possible to choose a branch before the job starts and depending that choose, that the checkout and build of the java application is either DEV or PROD branch?

This is part of the code of the jenkinfile.

```
node {
stage ('Code Checkout') {
            git branch: 'master or develop', ***-->would like here that can be choose master or dev***
                credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
                //url: 'https://user@bitbucket.org/ev/der-azure.git'
                url:  'https://user@bitbucket.org/ev/-service.git.git'
        }
stage ('Check Branch') { 
        sh 'git branch'
}

stage('Compile and Build WAR') {
        sh 'mvn clean compile war:war'
```

Comment: Can you specify exactly in your question how and where you want to choose the branch?

Comment: as I specify on the second image, in the "build with parameters". Right now is configured to choose Ansible code (which does the build) but I want to be able to choose the java code branch which is inside de jenkinfile

Comment: Just so you know, git-filter-branch is a tool to rewrite history- it's not involved with _selecting_ a branch! Consequently I'm going to remove the `git-filter-branch` tags and replace it with more appropriate ones.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea, why you have branch field bugged, 
but in advanced option 'Refspec' could help

[image]

Edit
Dont know, about the normal scm in your case, but as I noticed you are doing another checkout in the jenkinsfile, following step works

```
 stage('checkout') {
     checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://repository.foo/git/fooRepoName.git' ,
            credentialsId: 'credentialsIDToUseFromCredentialsPlugin']],
            branches: [[name:'refs/tags/TAGNAME']]],
        poll:false      
 }

stage('checkout') {
     checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://repository.foo/git/fooRepoName.git' ,
            credentialsId: 'credentialsIDToUseFromCredentialsPlugin']],
            branches: [[name:'BRANCHNAME']]],
        poll:false      
 }
```

Comment: I hide it thinking maybe will confuse people with the branch of the ansible code isntead with the code of java which is the code which I need to choose branch. Now I edited and is ok, check image. Where is the option you are saying and how doest it work? thanks

Comment: ah, you want to make it as parameter, then you should be able to make parametrized pipeline, refer eg [there](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines)

Comment: I already did that param build as you say, but this way I can choose Ansible_operations branch which is the code that do de java deployment. I want to be able to chose dev branch BUT OF THE JAVA code instead of the ansible operation. Basically want that the jenkinfile inside ansible operations do a CHECKOUT of DEV or MASTER (this is what I want to choose) of the java code.

Comment: well, if you define parameter branch with the name e.g. `custom_branch`, then you should be able to refer it in branch field probably as `${custom_branch}` ... or in the pipeline as well

Comment: yes that´s what I did as I said but I can only choose ansible code, how is it that I can choose Java code ? check jenkinsfile that I updated.

Comment: @yiyito check the edit of the post, I found it, its not possible to do the with this syntax, but if you will use class SCM syntax, then it works - [reference, docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/#-git-%20git) - `checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
     userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'http://git-server/user/repository.git']]])` you can find example for TAG use, and branch use